# form data doesn't insert into database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a form to insert data.when i click the submit button data doesn't insert to database.submit form without filling the form validations are not working. anyone can help me.

**controller**

```
//load client from table

    $data['client'] = $this->project_list_model->get_client();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Project Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('str_date', 'Start Date', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('end_date', 'End Date', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('add_project', $data);
    } else {
        $data = array(
        //'staff_id' => ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']),
                        'project_name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                        'client_id' => $this->input->post('client'),
                        'location' =>  md5($this->input->post('location')),
                        'start_date' => $this->input->post('str_date'),
                        'end_date' => $this->input->post('end_date')
                        );
        $result = $this->project_list_model->new_project($data);
        $data['message_display'] = 'Add Project Successfully !';
        $this->load->view('add_project', $data);

    }
}
```

**model**

```
//    add new project
function new_project($data){

    // Inserting in Table(students) of Database(college)
    $this->db->insert('project', $data);

}
```

**view**

```
<?php
echo form_open('project_list/add_project');
?>

<!--display successful message-->                 
<?php
if (isset($message_display)) {
    echo "<div class='message alert alert-success'>";
    echo $message_display;
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
<!--display successful message--> 

 <?php                                          
//hidden value user session id
echo form_hidden('staff_id',($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']) );
?>   
<div class="form-body">
     <div class="form-horizontal" role="form"> 

 <!--client-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-1"><b>Client Name </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <?php
       $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "client" style="width:80%; height:35px;"';
        echo form_dropdown('client',$client, set_value('client'), $attributes);?>
    </div>  
</div>
<!--client-->

<br>

<!--Category--> 
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-1"><b>Category </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
         <select name="type" style="width:80%; height:35px;" >
    <option selected="selected" >SELECT CATEGORY</option>
<?php
    // the gender array
    $type = array("New Build", "Maintain");

    // Iterating through the type array
    foreach($type as $type){
?>
        <option value="<?php echo strtolower($type); ?>"><?php echo $type; ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>

        </select> 
     </div>
</div>

 <!--/.Category--> 
 <br>

<!--name-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-1"><b>Project Name </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Project Name" style="width:79%; height:25px;" >
    </div>  
</div>
<!--/.name--> 

<br>

<!--location-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-1"><b>Location </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location" style="width:79%; height:25px;" >
    </div>  
</div>
<!--/.location-->

<br>

<!--Start Date-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-1"><b>Start Date </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" name="str_date" id="str_date" placeholder="Start Date" style="width:79%; height:25px;" >
    </div>  
</div>
<!--/.Start Date--> 

<br>

<!--End Date-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-1"><b>End Date </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" placeholder="Start Date" style="width:79%; height:25px;" >
    </div>  
</div>
<!--/.End Date--> 

<br>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-5"></label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn btn-success" value="Submit"> 
        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn btn-primary" value="Reset"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">

    </div>
</div>

<?php
echo form_close();
?>
<!--form_close-->
```

Comment: Add error handling around the insert call to determine what error you receive from MySQL. Without an actual error message it is somewhat difficult to tell what may have gone wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below function to print the validation errors in your form

```
<?php echo validation_errors() ?>
```

OR

```
<?php echo form_error('name');  //name will be name of your input field ?>
```

Comment: ok. then whats the problem to data doesn't insert into database

Comment: might be some validation errors. print the validation errors and check it.

Comment: form validation is working.but data doesn't insert into data base

Comment: please check your database structure. It might be some possible some column value are required and you are not passing that value and make sure `error reporting` is on so you can get the error.

Comment: raj i want to print array when i affter click the submit button.can you say where i should write "echo print_r($data); in my code

Comment: you can use `print_r($data)` in controller before you pass the data to model.

Comment: when i submit the form even array doesn't print.can you tell me the problem